# xslt - add elements to text but remove the in between element

Tags: xslt

I am not worked with XSLT lot. But Somehow, I am struggling to get the expected output for the below items.

Input 1:

```
<name>xxxx <xsample>dddd</xsample> zzzz</name>
```

Output for 1:

```
<p><t>xxxx dddd zzzz</t></p> // here I don't want to wrap the tag
```

Input 2

```
<name>xxxx <ysample>dddd</ysample> zzzz</name>
```

Output for 2:

```
<p><t>xxxx </t><t>dddd</t><t> zzzz</t></p>
```

I have tried with the below xslt code:

```
<xsl:template match="name">
<p>
<xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|comment()|processing-instruction()|text()"/>
</p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="name/text()[not(parent::ysample)]">
<t><xsl:value-of select="."/></t>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="name/ysample">
<t><xsl:value-of select="."/></t>
</xsl:template>
```

Anybody could you please help me with this?

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow.  Please read our [ask] page for instructions on how to improve this question.

Comment: I hope I improved my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check this in XSLT 2.0 with grouping

```
<xsl:template match="name">
    <p>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::text() or self::xsample">
            <t>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-group()"/>
            </t>
        </xsl:for-each-group>            
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot! It works well. But, in the first input "spaces" appeared two times, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this line

```
<xsl:template match="name//text()[not(parent::ysample)]">
```

There are two issues here

1. `name/text()` matches text nodes that are direct children of `name`, and so the condition `not(parent::ysample)`, which applies to the text node, will never be true as the parent will always be `name`
2. This is maybe a typo, but you probably want to check for `xsample` here, to implement your logic, especially because you already have a template matching `ysample`

Try this line instead:

```
<xsl:template match="name//text()[not(parent::xsample)]">
```